# How do I actually serve signed requests with oauth-php?

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-php

I am making an oauth provider and implemented everything in chapter 6 of http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/ , which is authenticating with OAuth. However, I am at a loss to how to actually serve authorized requests with the server (chapter 7).

Please point me to the right documentation or source code I would have missed.

Answer (score 0):

Google Code has [several libraries for doing OAuth](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/) (both server and client). Browse through them to see how thing are implement.s